# Validacion Request Laravel (SOLO 1 dato)

Tags: laravel, validación

Mi problema es que tengo una tabla donde cargan varios productos con la Id desde el 1 al 50 y una Id que es 999. En mi Request hago mi validacion en el atributo 'codigo' pero nose como hacer que ignore el 999 para que no salga error cuando escojo la id del 1 al 50 o el 999:

Mi Request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'subGrupo' => 'required|integer|min:999|max:999',
            'numero' => 'required|integer',
            'codigo' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:50|lt:999'
        ];
    }
```

Yo pense que era con 'lt' pero no, aun asi me sale error...como seria?? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar que un id existe en una base de datos, puedes usar [exist:table,column](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-exists). Ejemplo:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'subGrupo' => 'required|exist:productos,id',
         // ...
    ]
}
```

Donde `productos` es la tabla a consultar para saber si el `id` existe o no

Comment: Gracias! Me salio!